# Transparent image background is showing on ImageButton

Tags: android, android-layout, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

I have an image (picture 1) that has a transparent area around it that extends above and below the image itself (picture 2). When I add this image as an `ImageButton` in my xml and use `wrap_content`, that transparent area in picture 2 is becoming part of the button rather than just the button itself (picture 1). Picture 3 is the result. Does anyone know how to solve this?

[image: Button]

[image: Button]

[image]

Here's my XML:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/resume_button"
    android:src="@drawable/disabled_resume_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/new_checklist"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
```

Comment: post your xml please

Comment: Is your image is save in .png extension?

Comment: @Aakash I edited in my xml for the ImageButton

Comment: @mubeen Yes it is a .png file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the transparent area around your image, if its part of your image, contributes to the actual width and height of the image, imagine if the transparent part of the image was a coloured area rather than a transparent area and you can visulise how it would be part of your image, even though its transparent it is taking up an area that contributes to the height and width of the image

Comment: I thought this might be the case, but then how do I make an image button that is just the colored area itself?

Comment: in your graphic software select JUST the image without the transparent area copy and paste as a new image without the transparent area around it and that should work

Comment: we know there is a transparent area around your image but your graphic software just sees the width and height of the image, it dosnt recognize what the image is or what your trying to acheive it just recognizes the area the image as a whole takes up

Answer (score 2):

Do this :

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/resume_button"
    android:background="@drawable/disabled_resume_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/new_checklist"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
```

Answer (score -1):

"wrap_content" attribute just set the height of yout button to the height of yout image.
If you want to keep only the colored part of your image, just resize it! ;)